# How do I solve this difficult gcd question?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Find $gcd(m,n)$ if $(m^2 -mn-n^2)^2 = 1$

I was told it’s very difficult and I started by considering positive and negative cases. But I have no idea how it relates to gcd at all. Tried to form a linear combination but can’t see how it applies.

Comment: It is not difficult at all, I would dare to say it is trivial. If some $d>1$ divides both $m$ and $n$ then $d^4$ divides $1$, so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that

$$(m^2-mn-n^2)^2=1\implies m^2-mn-n^2=\pm 1$$

and we can see this last equality as

$$\color{red}mm-\color{red}{(m+n)}n=\pm1\iff (m,n)=1$$

Comment: How do you know if the coefficients are as such the gcd will be 1? I reached this step but I cant infer from it

Comment: @oldselflearner1959 It's a well known lemma or theorem: if $\;d\in\Bbb Z\;$ is such that there exist $\;x,y\in\Bbb Z\;$ with $\;mx+ny=d\;$ , then $\;(m,n)\,\mid\,d\;$ ...In fact, we can say $\;(m,n)\;$ is *the smallest* **positive** integer linear combination of $\;m,n\;$ .

Answer (score 3):

If $\gcd(m,n)>1$, then there's a prime $p$ such that $p\mid m$ and $p\mid n$. But then $p\mid(m^2-mn-n^2)^2$, which is impossible. Therefore $\gcd(m,n)=1$.